# Grid arrange title italics

Tags: titlebar, gridextra, r-grid

Hello All I'm trying to figure out how to get italicize one word in my grid arrange title. I've tried the bquote approach, but it won't graph the title. Thanks!

```
full_title <- bquote(paste(italic(Tamarix),"Green Foliage %"))

grid.arrange(Dry_16, Dry_17, nrow=1, ncol=2,top=full_title)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(gridExtra)
full_title <- expression(italic(Tamarix)~"Green Foliage %")

rg <- grid::rectGrob()
grid.arrange(rg, rg, ncol=2,top=full_title)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having issues graphing the title. [Found a solution to plotting the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008659/edit-style-of-grid-arrange-title-bold-italic-etc-r)                                                           
     Needed to add in 
   full_title <- TextGrob(expression(italic(Tamarix)~"Green Foliage %"))